# Make "Violin" sound come out upon entering Emit Sound

Tags: sound

How do I make this sound like a violin instead of a beep?

```
EmitSound[ Play[   Sin[600 π t], {t, 0, 1}]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Sound[SoundNote[...]]` to create the violin sound and `EmitSound` will play it on evaluation:

`EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote["D4", 1, "Violin"]]]`

`Sin[600\[Pi]]` corresponds to 300Hz. If you want the same pitch as your question, you need to start with a note close to 300Hz and shift the pitch up. By using a close note we minimize distortions.

From here https://pages.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html we can tell D4 is pretty close at 293.66Hz. To get 300Hz we just need to pitch shift D4 by $300/293.66$.

`EmitSound[AudioPitchShift[Sound[SoundNote["D4", 1, "Violin"]], 300/293.66]]`

Comment: By the way - you may notice there is a bug in _Mathematica_ where if you `EmitSound` and then run a different `EmitSound` while the first one is still playing, the sample rate can change and the second sound will be played at a very high or very low pitch.